# How to cherry publish my components library?

Tags: vue.js, components, lodash, publish, cherry-pick

I have a Vue components library which is all developed under the same repository, as repository per component is not sustainable. Out of the box, I can only publish it as a whole, but I want to be able to publish it both as a whole (like `lodash`) and Per-component (like `lodash.debounce`), so I can add a feature/fix a bug in some component rather quickly and publish it asap. What is the way to go? I already began looking into how Lodash does it, but it seems some trickery is involved, a custom build of sort.

Comment: How are you importing from that repository today?

Comment: I publish it to a private artifactory and then import it like a normal npm package. It's exposing itself as a plugin you'd install globally in your Vue.js app, or as an object of components which you can cherry-pick from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I may have found my answer: https://github.com/lerna/lerna